# How to create scrolling multiple tabs dynamically in android?

Tags: android

[image]

Has anyone done tabs like the above image?
If so can you please tell me how to create a Scrolling Multiple Tabs in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this implementation. It will do what you want.
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: i need to show only the scrolling topic tabs like the above image, i don't want to swipe the whole page, do you have sample for that,thanks for your concern so far